# Why didn't Dr. Strange transport the team back to earth using his sling ring?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

Dr. Strange and the team had a lot of time after Thanos left Titan after taking the Time Stone. Thanos had to get the rest of the stones, so there was a lot of time and Dr. Strange could have transported them back to earth using his sling ring, and Stark would not be stranded in space as is shown in the trailer for *Avengers: Endgame*.

So, why didn't he use it?

Comment: I'd contest the "lots of time", Thanos got the time stone, teleported to Earth, went straight for Vision, grabbed the stone and snapped his fingers. Took maybe 10 minutes. Sure that could have been enough, if the sling ring can go that distance and Strange would straight head for it, but after the fight the group on Titan is separated and barely ready to directly go for another round. They probably took a while to come together again.

Comment: Also, considering Thanos moved a _whole moon_ during the fight against the Avengers on his home planet, they may have chose not leave to avoid a considerable amount of collateral damages on Earth.

Answer (score 14):

Because that's the only possibility out of 14,000,605 where they can win.

> **Peter Parker**: Hey, what was that?
>
> **Doctor Strange**: [panting] I went forward in time to view alternate futures. To see all the possible outcomes of the coming conflict.
>
> **Peter Quill:** How many did you see?
>
> **Doctor Strange:** 14,000,605.
>
> **Tony Stark:** How many did we win?
>
> [Strange stares intently at Tony for a moment]
>
> **Doctor Strange:** ... One.

So Dr. Strange knew already how can they win, so if he is not doing something then it can be speculated that he didn't want to ruin that one in 14,000,605 chance to succeed.

Comment: I guess the answer to all questions regarding why Dr. Strange didn't do this is same. ;-P

Comment: @AJ ofcourse :D

Comment: After this scene, that is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think every answer to this (and everything about Doctor Strange) can be the 14 million possibilities thing. Sometimes (like here) there's a better explanation.

Something you assumed in your question is actually incorrect:

> **so there was a lot of time** and Dr. Strange could have transported them back to earth using his sling ring

There wasn't much time at all. The entire sequence from Thanos arriving in Wakanda (after leaving Titan) and until the "snap" is about 6 minutes in movie time, probably less for the characters since much of those minutes is in slow motion. During those few minutes we get a glimpse of the team on Titan picking themselves up, Tony Stark fixing his wound and so on. Then the snap happened and people started dying, including Dr. Strange. He didn't transport himself and others to earth simply because it happened too quickly.

Granted, it's possible that he knew that Stark has to live (which is why he gave his time stone) and maybe that also implies that Stark needs to be on Titan as well. However given the little time Strange could even react to what's happening, this isn't something that really needs that explanation.